# How do you get a transaction manager in a non web Spring Boot Appllication?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Is there a quick and easy way to get a ComamandLineRunner app to have a transaction manager?  I have the following setup:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class})
```

and

```
spring.main.web_environment=false
```

in the application.properties.  When I run the code:

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext context = application.run();
context.close();
```

I see this:

```
2014-10-26 11:00:59.956  INFO 4900 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean     : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
```

I see SQL echo out from the JPA Repository I've made but no transaction is committed to the db.  I've tried moving things into a service, making things as @Transactional etc.  I don't seem to be getting one popping into existence.

**Update 1:**
In case it matters I am using 1.2.0.M2.  I suspect @EnableAutoConfiguration still isn't doing the trick.  The debug output has this:

```
JpaBaseConfiguration#entityManagerFactory
  - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

JpaBaseConfiguration#entityManagerFactoryBuilder
  - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

JpaBaseConfiguration#jpaVendorAdapter
  - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

JpaBaseConfiguration#transactionManager
  - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)
```

The application.properties have a spring.datasource setup and Hibernate is getting the right dialect. I have created a @Service class with a method marked as @Transactional.  It still isn't getting commited however.

Comment: If you don't include the web classes your exclusions don't make sense. Spring Boot will detect what is on the class path and depending on that configure things. This includes JPA, Spring Data JPA and transactions. Make sure that you have `@Transactional` on those methods that need to be transactional else it will not be transactional.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot will automatically create a transaction manager when configuring JPA. Check out method `transactionManager` in class [JpaBaseConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.1.8.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaBaseConfiguration.java).

Note that this setup has nothing to do with the fact that the application is a web application or not.

So using `@Transactional` on Spring Beans will work correctly

Comment: So I suspect @EnableAutoConfiguration still isn't doing the trick.  The debug output has this:

Comment: Can you show the code that uses `@Transactional` that is not working?

Comment: So upon further review and adding the spring boot logging to the transactional processors things are working fine.  I had some extra annotation based config options that were conflicting.  Once I took those out the entity manager transaction is correctly instrumented in the service.